# can it be a good idea to partition available cores among GNU Make processes?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Has anybody seen a situation, where running `n` GNU Make processes each with

```
$ make -j <number of cores / n>
```

is faster than running them all with

```
$ make -j < number of cores>
```

and letting GNU Make take care of it.  I have never seen such an effect in my practice, and it seems to me, doing the former is pointless.  That is to say, maybe it is possible to cook up specific non-practical examples where such an effect would happen, but in real-world situation, no.

My question is, has anybody seen such an effect in their practice.

ADDED:  Of course it is assumed that the different processes are independent of each other and can  logically run simultaneously.

ADDED:  the question is NOT:  is it usually going to be faster to partition manually.  I know the answer to that, it is: NO.   The question is, CAN it happen in practice?  Has anybody seen it?

Especially I am interested in the answer of MadScientist :)

This question is On Topic of StackOverflow, because, the above lines are in programs, namely, wrapper scripts for GNU Make.  (Yes I know this is probably not going to fly, but at least I tried :)  )

Comment: No, it cannot be faster, and will almost always be slower (that is, almost always you'll get less parallelism).

Comment: And I should point out there is a perfectly good forum for asking questions like this which are not really on-topic for SO: the help-make@gnu.org mailing list.

Comment: @MadScientist ah yes I forgot about that completely for SO, yes Sir I will ask there

Answer (score 1):

Manual partitioning as you have described is likely to have strong negative effects:

- with no synchronization between the separate make processes, they are likely to try to rebuild the same files at the same time, leading to not only wasted work, but also failed builds due to overridden garbage inputs.
- even if you manage to partition the entire dependency chains without any overlap, you will have idle CPUs after the first partition finishes.

The only techniques I have seen that can improve makefile speed are:

- Place "more expensive" targets (i.e. binary with the most linking) earlier in the dependency lists, to prevent idle CPUs at the end.
- Include a generated makefile with cached dependencies rather than recalculating them every run even if they haven't changed.
- Use a system to avoid rebuilding files when source files change timestamp but not contents. I am only beginning to study what is possible here.

Comment: no of course I assumed, that it is OK to run them, so they don't have race conditions among them

Comment: thank you but I did not ask, is it usually a good idea, or what the techniques are.  I just wanted to know, "have you seen it", "have you heard of it"